# Agrupar y sumar registro repetidos en PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

Estoy haciendo un sistema en el cual a cada proyecto se le asigna un usuario. Cuando el usuario ingresa y ve el proyecto que le fue asignado, debera al final del dia colocar las horas trabajadas. Les muestro la relacion estre las tablas.

Tabla proyecto

```
idp | titulo
------------------
02  | Proyecto DD1
```

Tabla recurso(usuarios)

```
id | nombre
-------------------
01 | Usuario A1
02 | Usuario B1
```

Tabla Horas

```
idh | idpro | idrecurso | horas | fecha
-------------------------------------
01  | 02    | 01        | 4     | 2019-08-20
02  | 02    | 02        | 10    | 2019-08-20
03  | 02    | 02        | 8     | 2019-08-21
04  | 02    | 01        | 6     | 2019-08-21
```

Hago dos `INNER JOIN` para relacionar las tablas de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$glist = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM proyectos INNER JOIN horaspro ON horaspro.idpro = proyectos.idp INNER JOIN recurso ON horaspro.idrecurso = recurso.id WHERE idp = '".$idp."' GROUP BY idrecurso");
?>
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es:

```
Usuario A1 - 4 hs
Usuario B1 - 10 hs
Usuario B1 - 8 hs
Usuario A1 - 6 hs
```

Cuando el resultado tendria que ser:

```
Usuario A1 - 10 hs
Usuario B1 - 18 hs
```

Lo que trate de hacer es agregar al final de la consulta un `GROUP BY idrecurso` pero no me agrupa los registros repetidos. Tambien tengo que tomar solo los numero, sin importar el usuario, y sumarlos para obtener un total general de horas, lo trate de hacer com `SUM` pero tampoco me da resultado. Trate de usar unos ejemplor que encontre por la web, pero no resultaron y debe ser que tampoco los entiendo bien. Mil disculpas, pero mi falta de conocimiento, pero no logro resolverlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para el resultado que vos esperas(mostrar total de hs que tiene cada usuario) debes hacer un `group by` en combinación con función de agregado `sum()` como bién hizo Damian Perez, aunque no es necesario unir la tabla proyecto.
Y para la cláusula `idp = '".$idp."'` usas cláusula `where`
O sea que completa quedaria:

```
select recurso.nombre, sum(horaspro.horas)
from recurso inner join horaspro on horaspro.idrecurso = recurso.id
where horaspro.idpro ='".$idp."'
group by recurso.nombre
```

Para el total general de horas haces otra consulta usando también `sum()` pero sin el `group by` ya que no tenes que sumar `horas` agrupando por `usuario`, si no que más sencillamente tenes que sumar todas las `horas` de la tabla `horaspro` para determinado proyecto, asi:

```
select sum(horaspro.horas) from horaspro where horaspro.idpro ='".$idp."'
```

Comment: Gracias Juan, pero no logre tener resultados. Investigando un poco, me di cuenta que a `SUM()` le faltaba `AS` y no se porque, al agregarlo funciono. No se si eso esta bien o mal, pero al agregar  `AS horas` y agruparlo, me da el resultado que necesito. `$glist = $conn->query("SELECT *, sum(horaspro.horas) AS horas FROM proyectos INNER JOIN horaspro ON horaspro.idpro = proyectos.idp INNER JOIN recurso ON horaspro.idrecurso = recurso.id WHERE idp = '".$idp."' GROUP BY recurso.rnombre");`

Comment: Lo mismo hice con la suma de las horas totales: `$total = $conn->query("select sum(horaspro.horas) AS horas from horaspro where idpro ='".$idp."'");`

Comment: Ah mirá, que bueno que lo resolviste, gracias por el voto!. Si, varía en función de lo que uses para conectarte a la base de datos. Yo por ejemplo uso hibernate que usa HQL (no SQL, aunque es muuuy similar) y no hace falta el alias (as) en el campo de función agregada, pero si en el nombre de la tabla, acá copio y pego una consulta de mi programa para que veas: `select max(t.fecha) from Turno t where t.cancelado=0`

Comment: Otra cosa que te quería decir es para qué unís (inner join) todas las tablas, si en `horaspro` tenes todos los datos que necesitas excepto el nombre del usuario, que esa es la única unión que yo hice

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que la tabla `proyecto` y `recurso` tienen  un primary key llamado "id", asi le haria yo la sentencia sql:

```
select 
    recurso.nombre, sum(horas.horas)
from
    recurso
inner join
    horas
on
    horas.idrecurso = recurso.id
inner join
    proyecto 
on
    horas.idpro = proyecto.id   
group by
    recurso.nombre;
```

Y eso te da como resultado:

```
Usuario A1 - 10 hs
Usuario B1 - 18 hs
```

Comment: Gracias Damaian, pero si `select recurso.nombre` no funciona, ademas tambien tengo un `WHERE idp = '".$idp."'`, porque esta llamando al proyecto cuyo `idp` sea igual a `x` que es un dato traido desde un `get`.